# Can not get HTML as it is inside XML node

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

I'm doing a script which gets a xml file and show some text in it. A sample xml structure could be like:

```
<documento fecha_actualizacion="20221027071750">
<metadatos>
[...]
</metadatos>
<analisis>
[...]
</analisis>
<texto>
<dl>
<dt>1. Poder adjudicador: </dt>
<dd>
[...]
</dd>
</dl>
</texto>
</documento>
```

I'm trying to get the html inside 'texto' element as a string
(`'<dl><dt>1. Poder ad[...]</dt></dd>[...]'`)
, but when getting it, it is shown as:

```
Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [dl] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [dt] => Array ( [0] => 1. Poder adjudicador: [1] => 2. Tip
```

ordered by element (dl, dt, dd, etc).
I've tried every posible solution for querying that 'texto' element (with '//texto/text()', innerhtml, node(), nodeValue(), etc.) but it always return me the same.

How could I get something like `'<dl><dt>1. Poder ad[...]</dt></dd>[...]'`

Thank you!!

I have tried with selectors:

```
$texto = $xml->xpath('//texto/text()');
```

```
$texto = $xml->xpath('//texto/innerXml()');
```

```
$texto = $xml->xpath('//texto/node()');
```

```
$texto = $xml->xpath('//texto/nodevalue()');
```

Comment: The sample xml in your question is not well formed; please edit your question and fix so others can replicate the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fetch the parent nodes (`texto`), iterate and save each child node as XML:

```php
$documento = new SimpleXMLElement(getXMLstring());

foreach ($documento->xpath('//texto') as $texto) {
  $result = '';
  foreach ($texto->children() as $content) {
    $result .= $content->asXML(); 
  }

  var_dump($result);
}
```

Output:

```
string(59) "<dl>
<dt>1. Poder adjudicador: </dt>
<dd>
[...]
</dd>
</dl>"
```

SimpleXML is an abstraction focused on element nodes. It has limits. If the `texto` element can have non-element child nodes they will not be included. In this case you need to use DOM.

```php
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML(getXMLString());
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//texto') as $texto) {
  $result = '';
  foreach ($texto->childNodes as $content) {
    $result .= $document->saveXML($content); 
  }

  var_dump($result);
}
```

Additionally `DOMXpath::evaluate()` supports full Xpath 1.0, including expressions that return scalar values.